# What is to Stone space of the free sigma-algebra on countably many generators?

Tags: measure-theory, lattice-theory, boolean-algebras

I asked the question on MSE.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898377/what-is-the-stone-space-of-the-free-sigma-algebra-on-countably-many-generators

The answer I got, however, seems disputed. I just thought that someone here could answer the question for sure. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got a wrong answer on Math Stackexchange from Daron. The free Boolean algebra on countably many generators is the Boolean algebra of clopens of $2^\omega$ (topologized with the product topology), and the free $\sigma$-algebra on countably many generators is the Baire $\sigma$-algebra of $2^\omega$, which, as $2^\omega$ is metrizable, is the same as the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. A good source for this is Halmos's book *Lectures on Boolean Algebras*.

To see that Daron's claim is wrong, observe that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is a complete Boolean algebra, but the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $2^\omega$ is not, because the least upper bound of the family of all singletons contained in a non-Borel subset of $2^\omega$ does not exist. The algebras $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathrm{Borel}(2^\omega)$ cannot be isomorphic because any Boolean algebra isomorphic to a complete Boolean algebra is complete.

The "$\sigma$-Stone space" of $\mathrm{Borel}(2^\omega)$, *i.e.* the set of ultrafilters closed under countable intersection, or equivalently the $\{0,1\}$-valued countably additive measures, does have a nice description, as it is isomorphic to $2^\omega$ itself.

Unfortunately, the ordinary Stone space of $\mathrm{Borel}(2^\omega)$ does not have a nice description, except tautologous rephrasings of the usual one, such as saying it is the space of $\{0,1\}$-valued finitely-additive Borel measures on $2^\omega$. I think this follows from the fact that there exist models of ZF where the axiom of choice fails and there are no nonprincipal ultrafilters on $\omega$. Any ultrafilter on $\mathrm{Borel}(2^\omega)$ that is not closed under countable intersections can be used to define a non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$.

Comment: Thank you Robert for your reply. May I ask you what you mean exactly by the "$\sigma$-Stone space" of the free sigma-algebra on $\omega$ generators; I am not familiar with this concept. Is it what Halmos calls a $\sigma$-space (i.e a space in which the closure of open Borel sets is open)?

Comment: Halmos defines a $\sigma$-space to be a Stone space (*i.e.* a compact Hausdorff zero-dimensional space) in which the closure of every open *Baire* set is open. A Boolean algebra is $\sigma$-complete iff its Stone space is a $\sigma$-space. Another name for this property is "basically disconnected".

Comment: @puzzled By the "$\sigma$-Stone space" of a $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra $A$, I mean the set of $\sigma$-ultrafilters $X$ equipped with the natural $\sigma$-algebra defined on them by $A$ (as a measurable space without any topology). This is something that can be found in Sikorski's *Boolean Algebras*, section 24 (by specializing the cardinal $\mathfrak{m}$ to $\aleph_0$).

Comment: @puzzled If you don't mind self-promotion, I describe the construction of this space in Section III of:
http://people.cs.aau.dk/~furber/papers/unrestrictedstone.pdf
using the notation $\mathcal{U}^\sigma(A)$ where $A$ is a $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra (proofs are in the appendix).

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, @Robert, $\sigma$-Stone spaces are not $\sigma$-spaces (they are not extremally disconnected). is there any chance I can force it?

Comment: Also, @Robert, you mentioned in your answer that the $\sigma$-Stone space of $Bor(2^\omega)$ is isomorphic to $2^\omega$. Where can I find a proof of that statement?

Comment: @puzzled It seems my terminology has you confused. What I was calling the $\sigma$-Stone space of a $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra is not a topological space -- it is a measurable space (if you try to put the Stone topology on it, you will get too many open sets). There is no abstract notion of "$\sigma$-Stone space" as a topological space. The reason that $\mathcal{U}^\sigma(\mathrm{Borel}(2^\omega)) \cong 2^\omega$ is that $2^\omega$, equipped with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, is $\sigma$-perfect. See Theorems 5 and 6 of the article I linked above.

Comment: The isomorphism in question is called $\eta_X$ at that point in the article.

Comment: @puzzled It also seems there is still some confusion about $\sigma$-spaces. Just to re-iterate, the Stone space of a $\sigma$-Boolean algebra is always a $\sigma$-space, which is a Stone space such that the closure of every **Baire** open set is open. For a Stone space $X$, extremally disconnected is a strictly stronger property than being a $\sigma$-space, corresponding to the equivalent properties: 1. $X$ is the Stone space of a *complete* (not just $\sigma$) Boolean algebra, 
2. The closure of every open set is open in $X$.

Comment: @puzzled As every open set is Borel, it is therefore the case that if $A$ is a $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra that is not complete, its Stone space has open sets (therefore Borel sets) that are not Baire sets.

Comment: @puzzled But remember that the last two comments are about the Stone space, a topological space consisting of all ultrafilters, not the $\sigma$-Stone space, which is a measurable space consisting of only the ultrafilters closed under countable meets, which is what the previous two comments are about.